# Disable default user/password browser pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, popup, mobile-safari

When a user submits a request with a incorrect user or password to my server via my web app, mobile safari and other browsers pop-up a form asking for the correct user/password.

I wish to disable this default behavior and handle the errors myself.  
Any suggestions would be welcome as I cannot find any relevant information on what I presume is a common problem (another user asked this same question over a year ago and never received a answer).

Comment: What are you currently using to validate your log-in form? This behavior is not part of the Safari Mobile UI, it is something that your code is doing.

Comment: Are you talking about HTTP Basic Authentication popups? How are those done server-side then?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am using a GET request to a REST api.  When the response is generated the browser reads the 401 error and pops up up what is possibly the HTTP Basic Authentication popup that @deceze is mentioning.

Comment: So try to check if the user is authenticated BEFORE you make the protected API call.

Comment: In order for an HTTP Basic authentication popup to open the server needs to send appropriate headers. A 401 by itself doesn't cause that.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, clearly I need to better understand the request/response headers and research the HTTP basic authentication.  Will answer this when I find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my authentication issues but using CURL and setting the appropriate headers.  It looks like I was asking for a solution that does not exist to a question that can be avoided.